# How to properly setup two .git repository for django project

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have django project with gitlab repository.  I want to integrate another one **github repository**. Am I should start integrating github repo by **git init** If yes,  is it mean that I will have locally two  .git folders.  Can anyone guide me trough this step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to run `git init` again.

1. Simply create a new empty repository on GitHub. Make sure to NOT add a README/License, because then the repository would NOT be empty.
2. GitHub should then give you commands under the **"…or push an existing repository from the command line"** title, for example:

```
# DO NOT RUN THIS, THIS IS JUST AN EXAMPLE, see step (3)
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/temporary.git
git push -u origin master
```

3. Open a terminal in the directory of your existing repository, modify the commands given to you by GitHub, but replace `origin` with the word `github`, for example:

```
# DO NOT RUN THIS, THIS IS JUST AN EXAMPLE
git remote add github git@github.com:username/temporary.git
git push -u github master
```

This will sync the master branch (and the history leading up to it) with GitHub.

If there are other branches other than master that you want to push, simply run the `push` commands with those branches as well.

This simply syncs your repository with GitHub - it does not create a "new" repository. Your local repository on your computer now has 2 [remotes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes). One for the original clone (Gitlab) - called `origin`, and one for GitHub - called `github`.